# How to filter a list<int> by comparing against a single int variable?

Tags: c#, list, console

I have a `list<int>` with values like `10`, `20`, `30`, `56`. I also have a local variable `int _marks = 30`.

How can I print out the values in the list that are less than the value of `_marks`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Where()` from `System.Linq` namespace to filter the array.  It returns `IEnumerable<int>` object. And for printing the elements in this collection we can use [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. It performs the specified action on each element of the `List<T>`. And in case of single argument you can pass function by itself:

```
marks.Where(x => x < _marks).ToList().Foreach(Console.WriteLine);
```

By the way if you are newbie you can use non-LINQ solution also:

```
foreach(int item in marks)
{
    if(item < _marks)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Also, as @Kjartan said, if the list is ordered, then it may be good option to use `TakeWhile()` or `SkipWhile()` functions to get desired elements:

```
// If the list is ordered in ascending order
marks.TakeWhile(x => x < _marks).ToList().Foreach(Console.WriteLine);

// If the list is ordered in descending order
marks.SkipWhile(x => x >= _marks).ToList().Foreach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Wouldn't the ordering be at least as costly as the where? Hence I doubt we'd win anything if we ordered the list first.

Comment: @PaulKertscher I agree with you. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've got several options here. A couple of examples:

```
var yourList = new List<int>{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 56, 60, 70};
var _marks = 55;

// Get a IEnumerable containing values matching your condition ( ie. < _marks):
var selected = yourList.Where(i => i < _marks);
```

Alternative if you know the values are sorted by increasing values (this will avoid iterating through the whole list unnecessarily):

```
var selected = yourList.TakeWhile(i => i < _marks);
```

To print, do e.g.:

```
selected.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Comment: `TakeWhile()` is good option if the collection is ordered. There will be performace difference if the list is huge.